# To cut down on comment chatter, remove support for "@" except to invite someone to comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, chat, notifications

The most useful comments are aimed at the OP. Some of them should persist long after talk on the answer has died down. Notifications tend to suck people in who have run out of useful things to say to anyone who may like to read the question or answer in the future. And in my experience people tend to be a *little* nicer in 1:1 chat conversations than this weird penning-letters-back-and-forth form that has become internet comments.

So my conclusion is there really isn't a strong use case for mailbox notifications in chat discussions. Useful comments are aimed primarily at future visitors or the OP (and the OP, generally, once, not over a volley). The @ pings are really counterproductive to our goal of keeping chat on chat and comments useful and generally friendly.

Answer (score 1):

re: "The @ pings are really counterproductive" I think you'll have to provide some metrics before we could really relate with this suggestion. I would wager that a lot of people find notifications have no effect on productivity and only serve to improve discussion quality (compared to simply missing messages).

Granted there have been some studies proposing that notifications serve to interrupt workflow *in general*, but to my knowledge those aren't conclusive or widely accepted except in certain circles. I also don't know that the user areas of Stack Exchange is a place where a workflow can really be interrupted.

I *could* see this being a concern for moderators (or maybe even on review queues), so maybe this is a use case for fine-grained notification control, but at this point I don't see it as a good general suggestion.